# phpQuery and accented chars

Tags: php, phpquery, non-ascii-characters

When I parse html using phpQuery, I got bad results with accentuated chars.
The following code echo craps...

```
<?php 
    require_once 'phpQuery.php';
    $dom = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML('<p>é</p>');
    echo $dom->text(); //bad result
?>
```

Anybody know about accentuation in phpQuery?

I'm using netbeans on windows 2008 server with firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add on your page :

```
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

You welcome !

And by the way, I believe you use Windows 2008 Server and not Windows 7 Server ...

Comment: Well I don't know if you have JS in your page but if that the case, you can still try this function : 

[http://www.navioo.com/javascript/tutorials/Javascript_utf8_encode_1529.html]

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($dom->text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
string utf8_decode ( string $data )
```

or

```
string utf8_encode ( string $data )
```

I believe as my previous answer that it must be a UTF-8 problem.